# Link to the post displays ID instead of slug

Tags: permalinks

I've met a strange error on my page. After I do an internal link in my site, like that in the page editor

```
<a href="/page-name">
```

then in the page source code it displays

```
<a href="/?page_id=784">
```

instead of the slug.

Have anyone met something like that? How can I change that to display slug instead? I got the permalink setting `%postname%` and all other internal link displays fine, just that one...

Comment: What do you mean ?  I got line like that
<p class="contact-visit" style="text-align: center;"><a class="hover_orange" href="http://odent.pl/profil-pacjenta/umow_sie/" target="_blank">Umów Wizytę</a></p>  but instead I got the ID in the page source code

Comment: ' Added slash, so editor don't convert it into a code, it is not an error ;) ' - i meant stackoverflow editor ^^ i dont have that in my code. I even changed that in my database manually... but still doesn't help ... I'm using page builder

Comment: yea, but It still doesn't help with the problem ^^

Comment: nope but will  hopefully help others get a better understanding. I will remove my comments now, since it's mainly about the formatting ;-) It could be from the page builder you're using or other plugins, or even the theme. Did you check it without the page builder activated?

Comment: I think it started to work, after manauall database change...Just had to take some time to refresh on page ...

Comment: ok great - you could also post an answer explaining it futher and accept it to close the question.

Comment: sure, but actually I still don't know why did that happen ^^

Answer (score 1):

What your explaining is the normal linking method for WordPress when you are linking to a post that has not yet been published. Based on your question I think that's what occurred to you.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me is that the post was **future** post (marked as "Scheduled" in the admin). They are not supposed to be published until that date, therefore, link won't work unless you're logged in.

In my case, I could make my events page using [The Future Is Now](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-future-is-now/), a wonderfully simple WordPress plug-in.

Hope it helps!